# How is the correlation matrix using cor calculated?

Tags: r, correlation, pearson-correlation

I implemented my own correlation function in R. Surprisingly I get slightly different results when using the built-in `cor` function. The differences seem to disappear when `n` the number of observations are big enough.

My function:

```
corr = function(X) {
  Q = X - colMeans(X)
  S_ = colSums(Q**2)
  S = sqrt(S_ %*% t(S_))
  covarr = t(Q) %*% Q
  corrr_ = covarr / S
  return(corrr_)
}

library(mvtnorm)
set.seed(247)
X = rmvnorm(10, sigma = matrix(c(1,0.8,0.8,1), ncol=2)) # change 10 to 100, 1000, or 10000
corr(X)
cor(X)
```

For `n=10` I get 0.8490966 vs. 0.8465363, so the change is in the 3rd decimal. For `n=1000` I get 0.7960206 vs. 0.7960925, so the change is in the 5th decimal.

Comment: You can see the underlying code with `body(cor)`.

Comment: Look into the C source code of [C_cor](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/src/cov.c) that `cor()` calls internally.

Comment: @jay.sf I've looked, it's a complicated code, this is why I ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of the function should be this since R stores matrices column by column and not row by row

```
Q = t(t(X) - colMeans(X))
```

or

```
Q = X - matrix(colMeans(X), nrow(X), ncol(X), byrow = TRUE)
```

or

```
Q = scale(X, TRUE, FALSE)
```

or even this which is not the same Q but in the end gives the same answer

```
Q = scale(X)
```

If we use cov2cor from the base of R then

```
corr = function(X) {
  Q = scale(X)
  cov2cor(crossprod(Q))
}
```

Comment: Yep. Or `Q = sweep(X, 2, colMeans(X))`.

Comment: Thanks. I always mix R and python "broadcasting"